# Accessing html in an opened window from the parent window

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am opening a window like such:

```
var w = window.open("/path", "_blank")
w.document.write('<div class="newDiv">new div</div>');
```

How do you use jquery to access ".newDiv" (or is this even possible)?

I want to do this:

```
$(".newDiv").text("New text for newDiv");
```

But this does not currently work.

Comment: Do you need jQuery? Could you do `w.document.getElementsByClassName('newDiv')[0]`?

Comment: This works: w.document.getElementsByClassName('newDiv')[0].innerHTML = "New text for newDiv"; Thanks.